# Testing a nested async call react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following component with a react hook containing a nested async call written in typescript.

```
const sampleComponent: FunctionComponent = (): ReactElement => {
    const [ detail, setDetail ] = useState<detailObject>(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        getConfigs();
    }, [ detail != undefined ]);

    const getConfigs = () => {
        getConfig().then((configResp: any) => {
            if(response.status === 200) {
                getConfigDetail(configResp.data.id).then((response) => {
                    if(response.status === 200) {
                        setDetail(response.data)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        //Some UI related to the responses.
    )
}
```

I test this with the following test.

```
const configList = jest.spyOn(api, "getConfigList");
const configDetail = jest.spyOn(api, "getConfig");

configList.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(configListRequestResponse); // these are sample responses
});

configDetail.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(configDetailsRequestResponse); // these are sample responses
})

test("Test proper rendering config component", async () => {
   await act(async () => {
      render(
          <Provider store={ store }>
              <sampleComponent/>
          </Provider>
      );
      await waitFor(() => expect(configList).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
      await waitFor(() => expect(configDetail).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
      expect(screen.getByTestId("remote-configs")).toBeInTheDocument();
   });
});
```

When I run this test, I get the following error.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
    > 95 |       setDetail(response.data);
         |       ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

you should create a renderWithState function in which you define the provider as a wrapper like so

```
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createTestStore } from '../redux';
import { AppStore } from '../redux/types';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { rootReducer } from './reducers';
const createTestStore = (store: AppStore) => createStore(rootReducer, store);

export const renderWithState = (Component: ReactElement, options?: { state: AppStore }) => {
  const store = createTestStore({dummystate:"hello"});
  const Wrapper: FC = ({ children }) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;

  return render(Component, { wrapper: Wrapper });
};

describe('index tsx', () => {
  it('it should render mocked state provider', () => {
    const Hello = () => <div>hello world</div>;
    renderWithState(<Hello />, { state: initStore });
  });
});
```

also to test async behaviour do it like below

```
  it('it renders text dummy dummies on click', async () => {
    const { queryByRole, getByText } = renderWithState(
      <Router>
        <CustomDropDown/>
      </Router>,
      {
        state: sb.store,
      },
    );

    const toggler = queryByRole('dropdown-toggle');

    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.click(toggler!);
      await waitForElement(() => getByText('dummy'));
      await waitForElement(() => getByText('dummies'));
    });
  });
```

hope this helps you on your way